# How to upgrade Android Gradle Plugin on MacOS?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I try build AAB Android Package for Flutter app using Android Studio on Mac. But when I try do it, I get error like this:
[image]
I see a lot of solutions, but it works or Windows, or on pure java/kotlin solution (not Flutter)

How to update Android Gradle Plugin? My Gradle settings looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found solution.
I cannot make bundle from flutter project, but I can do it from android part of flutter project.
If I open my solution on main directory of repo I see:
[image]

But `Generate Signed Bundle / APK` return error like in image from question post.
[image]

Moreover, `AGP Upgrade Assistant...` not working at all (nothing happen after press it).

But if I open project at `android` folder inside root of repo, on top menu of IDE I see other options like this:

[image]

And:

[image]

And these two features works as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Open build.gradle in the Android folder in your project. Then you can see a gradle version specified in it. Change it to the required version and try again

```dart
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```